# Animate MapView v2 camera without loosing bearing and tilt

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to animate MapView camera but want to preserve the bearing and tilt use has set.

I tried below code :

```
float bearing = map.getCameraPosition().bearing;
float tilt = map.getCameraPosition().tilt;

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(
                    (mapBoundsBuilder.build().northeast.latitude + mapBoundsBuilder
                                    .build().southwest.latitude) / 2,
                    (mapBoundsBuilder.build().northeast.longitude + mapBoundsBuilder
                                    .build().southwest.longitude) / 2))
        .zoom(map.getCameraPosition().zoom).bearing(bearing)
        .tilt(tilt).build()));

// Set mapView camera to include all locations in mapBoundsBuilder.
// Set width and height to screen size. Set padding to 50 px,
// duration to 2 sec.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
            mapBoundsBuilder.build(), size.x, mapViewHeight,
            CAMERA_PADDING), 2000, null);
```

But this does not preserve bearing and tilt.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CameraUpdate, which changes only target and zoom:

```
cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newTarget, newZoom);
```

The remaining question may be how to calculate the new zoom value.
It depends a bit on how you want to treat the different map width in case the map is tilted. But in principle you need the ratio between the current width of the map and the desired width.
With that ratio you can calculate the new zoom value as follows:
(Ratio is greater than 1 if map shows a bigger area than needed and smaller than 1 if it shows a smaller area than needed.)

```
float zoomIncrement = (float) (Math.log(ratio) / Math.log(2));
float newZoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom + zoomIncrement;
```

In my case I am using the smaller of the two distances from nearLeft to nearRight and from nearLeft to farLeft as the map "diameter" and divide this by the diagonal (distance between northeast and southwest) of the LatLngBounds which contains all my locations. As the LatLngBounds is oriented towards north but the map may be turned by e.g. 45 degrees, this ensures, that the locations will always fit into the map:

```
double innerDiameterOfMap = getInnerDiameterOfMap(map);
double outerDiameterOfBounds = getOuterDiameterOfBounds(bounds);
double ratio = innerDiameterOfMap / outerDiameterOfBounds;

private double getOuterDiameterOfBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
    return getDistance(bounds.northeast,
            bounds.southwest);
}

private double getInnerDiameterOfMap(GoogleMap map) {
    double innerDiameterOfMap;
    // The diameter of the inner circle is given by the shortest side.
    VisibleRegion visibleRegion = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    double side1 = getDistance(visibleRegion.nearLeft,
            visibleRegion.nearRight);
    double side2 = getDistance(visibleRegion.farLeft,
            visibleRegion.nearLeft);
    innerDiameterOfMap = Math.min(side1, side2);
    return innerDiameterOfMap;
}
```

For calculating the distance (method getDistance) between two LatLng you will find a lot of solutions in SO.